# Modern C++ way of starting and terminating a linux program

Tags: c++, linux, fork, exec

I have a C++ program that, based on user input, needs to start and stop a given Linux program.

I've simplified the logic I'm currently using in the following code:

```
int pid = fork();

if (pid == -1)
{
    //Handle error
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
    execlp("my_program", nullptr);
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    //Main program stuff

    if(/* user selects close "my_program"*/)
    {
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    }

    //Other main program stuff
}
```

Everything is working, but I was wondering if there were any other approaches, maybe more in the modern C++ style, that could be used in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a classic use of RAII?

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Process (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html). `bp::child` can launch (asynchronously, unlike std::system) a process, which can be waited for, terminated, etc.

Comment: Yes, there are other approaches, but if your program is already working correctly then what are you looking to gain?  "[Modern] C++ style" is a means to an end, not an end in itself.

Comment: @m88 thank you, I will have a look at that

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think that it is always good to try and learn new ways of doing things, even if it is something you already done thousands of time.

Comment: I am in no way against learning new things, @Mdp11, or new ways of doing things.  But here at SO it does help to be clear about your purposes, and you present the question as being about a specific program, not about launching and managing processes in general.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I actually thought my intent was clear and was not about anything specific, since I wanted to understand how to start and stop any program. If I was not, tell me where I was not clear enough so I can edit the question to avoid misunderstandings, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at boost::process.

There are several ways a process can be spawned. For example, in your example, you fork the process, but you don't close the cloned file descriptors in the child process. That is an often forgotten practice by those that invoke fork and can lead to binding to port problems (port/address already in use) or other hard-to-debug issues.

Even boost didn't do that quite correctly for some time.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that

Answer (score 2):

The modern way would be to use a library like Boost.Process https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/process.html or Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html.